# Error "Application windows are expected to have a root view controller" (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, loadview, mopub

I've created a blank iPhone app project and would like to show a full-screen advertisement during app launch.

I tried to install the ad by following this guideline: https://github.com/mopub/mopub-ios-sdk/wiki/Interstitial-Integration-For-iOS

That's what I've done finally:

[image: In ViewController.h]

[image: In ViewController.m]

Actually all codes are just copied from the previous link.

However, an error shows when app runs:

> **Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch**

I think this error may probably related to the loadView method, because if I remove the loadView method, the error disappeared.

In fact, this error seems common as it can be easily searched on the internet, but I don't know how loadView is related to it, and how can it be solved in my case.

Any solutions? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Show the code in AppDelegate.m. Specifically the code in the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method.

Answer (score 7):

You probably need to do this:

Add

```
#import "ViewController.h"
```

to the top of AppDelegate.m

And in AppDelegate.m, your application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method should have some code like this.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // ... Other code

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];

    self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

 [vc.view addSubview:self.tab_controller.view];

 [self.window setRootViewController:vc];
```

OR

```
UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

 [vc.view addSubview:yourClass.view];

 [self.window setRootViewController:vc];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you started with an empty template and added a storyboard, you need to do a couple of things:

You need to delete all the lines (except return statement) inside didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
        return YES;
}
```

In project settings ->General, select your storyboard as the main interface

Answer (score 0):

Attached snapshot to help you[image]

At the right side check there is one option under attribute inspector which asks to set as "is rootView controller"